# How to get the firebase topics that I am subscribed to?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase in an Android app and I need to know all topics that a device is subscribed. I know I can do that using Google Instance Id API with a GET request to:

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/[token]?details=true
```

Sending the `api_key` as "Authorization" header but I wanna know if there is another way to do this from Firebase SDK?

Comment: Why do you want to subscribe to topics? Firebase does a good job with abstracting that concept out of your hands.

Comment: I don't wanna subscribe to topics, I just want to know the topics that a device is subscribed to.

Comment: Just curious as to why are you searching for an alternative way?

Comment: If ever Firebase SDK allows you to get all the topics, are you willing to put the "Authorization" key in the client app? It's a secret and should stay a secret key.

Comment: I'm looking for a different way because I want to use the android sdk to do this without have to send the api_key as header in every http request